# Is it valid to edit "how to do off-topic X" questions into "Where to ask how to do X"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, off-topic

Some day this week I came across a question that a asked about a Microsoft product licence thing.

The question title and body was a clear "Where to ask about ..."

I agreed with one comment that most likely "not on the SE network at all, because off-topic". But I was still surprised that the question had at least 2 downvotes at that point.

Only later I figured: initially, the OP had asked *this* community to solve his problem. It was another MSE user who turned "how to do X" into "where to ask about X".

A side result was: that the OP came back later "but I still have that problem, so how to do X" in comments. The original questioner didn't get that asking "how to X" is off-topic here. The OP was *still* looking for people to help with X.

So, simply wondering: is it an appreciated practice of editing "lost soul" questions like that?

Comment: Are you referring to *MSE* specifically, or to sites on the SE network more broadly? If the former, does https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293420/when-is-it-worth-to-edit-an-off-topic-question-on-mse-into-a-site-recommendation help?

Answer (score 9):

I [do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/341779/revisions) only if I see some indications that the author of the post has a hunch about the nature of Meta Stack Exchange.

In this case, they tagged their question [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) *and* indicated they weren't sure about the correct Stack Exchange site. Especially the former is an indication that this is more than just a run-of-the-mill 'lost soul'. I know the above isn't a 100% fool proof method, but on the other hand: not much is lost when I'm proven wrong by later actions.